# Running too many tasks on UI Thread

Tags: java, android, xml, android-framelayout, android-relativelayout

I have been getting the above error for quite some time. Upon a lot of prodding around, I've come to the conclusion that its my xml itself which is causing this issue. I have commented ALL of my code in my java file and tried to load JUST THE LAYOUT. Even then the warning keeps popping up. I am herein attaching my xml file, hoping someone can shed some light on this. I would like to know what are the "heavy duty" work being performed which is causing my app to "skip frames".

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:background="@drawable/back_1"
    tools:context="com.avantaritech.flipa.MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/first_bar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/overflow_home"
            android:id="@+id/nav_button"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/fill"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sync_green"
            android:id="@+id/sync_button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
            android:id="@+id/view" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view"
            android:id="@+id/mega_relative"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/viewpager_holder_first"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager_first"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_225sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
                <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/indicator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager_first"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_110sdp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager_holder_first"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:overScrollMode="always"
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    >
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/textbox_home">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/hr"
                            android:id="@+id/hr_image_home"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Heart Rate"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:id="@+id/hr_text_home"

                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="end|top" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="00"
                            android:id="@+id/home_hr"
                            android:textSize="35sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="BPM"
                            android:textColor="@color/skin_v1"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_75sdp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
                    </FrameLayout>
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:background="@color/textbox_home">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/steps"
                            android:id="@+id/steps_image_home"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="00"
                            android:id="@+id/home_steps"
                            android:textSize="30sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="STEPS"
                            android:textColor="@color/skin_v1"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_75sdp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Steps"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:id="@+id/steps_text_home"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_30sdp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />


                    </FrameLayout>
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_25sdp"
                        android:background="@color/textbox_home">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/dist"
                            android:id="@+id/dist_image_home"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="00"
                            android:id="@+id/dist_textview_home"
                            android:textSize="30sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="METERS"
                            android:id="@+id/dist_unit"
                            android:textColor="@color/skin_v1"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_75sdp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Distance"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:id="@+id/dist_text_home"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />


                    </FrameLayout>
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:background="@color/textbox_home">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/pace"
                            android:id="@+id/pace_image_home"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="00"
                            android:id="@+id/pace_textview_home"
                            android:textSize="30sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="STEPS/MIN"
                            android:textColor="@color/skin_v1"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_75sdp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Avg. Pace"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:id="@+id/pace_text_home"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
                    </FrameLayout>
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:background="@color/textbox_home">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cal"
                            android:id="@+id/cal_avg_image_home"
                            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="00"
                            android:id="@+id/cal_avg_textview_home"
                            android:textSize="30sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="KCAL/MIN"
                            android:textColor="@color/skin_v1"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_75sdp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Avg. KCAL"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                            android:id="@+id/kcal_text_home"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mega_relative"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/nav_button"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                android:id="@+id/workout_start"
                android:src="@drawable/run"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should limit the use of FrameLayouts inside the LinearLayout and then inside the HorizontalScrollview

Comment: What do you mean 'limit'? Like, use fewer Framlayouts? I need a tile of boxes which scroll. What would be your suggestion? :)

Comment: As a general rule, you should avoid RelativeLayout s as the root views of your layout. Same goes for LinearLayout s with weight attributes. However, I don't think this is the reason for your error. Probably something else is going on.

Comment: @SantuReddy In my opinion it is not whole XML file.

Comment: I have tried to comment it out partially and then see, issue still persists.

Comment: Add whole xml file, if this what u add is only part, i am afraid about whole file.

Comment: You should use fragments to build different sections of tiles. Using these many layouts will slow the app and may be that is the cause of your error. Post your Logcat if possible.

Comment: @sharadchauhan I have commented out my entire code and just left the bar at the top, just to see which part is causing the issue, and yet my issue still persists. Now I'm just baffled.

Comment: @ArturSzymański this is the whole xml file.

Comment: then make a new xml file using just one layout(to check), use it in activity and check if the error is still there.  dont include this xml file. Let us know if that xml file shows the error too.

Comment: @SantuReddy, did you enable hardware acceleration in your manifest ?

Comment: @Stanislasdrg yes i have.

Comment: @sharadchauhan I just checked with a blank XML file. No, then my issue does not persist. No error then.

Comment: @SantuReddy How many frames is it skipping ? Are you working with the emulator or using a phone ? Are the activity and Fragment lifecycle well implemented in your app ?

Comment: Yeah, that means you are making your xml file heavier. If you want to scroll things then use scrollview and inside it use your fields using on one relativelayout. Dont use too many child layouts.

Comment: @Stanislasdrg I am working with a Nexus 5, 5X and OnePlus 2. Yes, the viewpager which I have used uses fragments. And I have implemented that without any issues.

Comment: @sharadchauhan Yes I know that, but what I'm unable to find out is what exactly is making it heavy. Like, which specific part. As I said, I have commented out my ENTIRE xml file and the problem still persists.